# Matlab commands FIR filter

Tags: matlab, filter

I have this homework where I have a signal, actually a sum of signals and it is requested to make a FIR filter of it which will cut frequencies above 40 Hz and will have width N=41 and for its construction use a squared window.How I am supposed to do that ,I have trouble finding the commands,then it says to print with semilogy the transfer function and the impulse response of the filter.Please help me by providing me the necessary commands and the methodology.Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is supposed to be *your* homework.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the Signal Processing Toolbox?

1. use the `fdatool` to find out what you actually want.
2. Decide which filter you want to use and have a look into the matlab
   documentation of that filter, it will provide you the code you need
3. you will get a transfer function structure `tf`
4. you can plot the `tf`-system with `bode(sys)` and you get the frequency response

If you don't have the toolbox you have to design the filter by hand, determine the transfer function and use `tf( numerator-vector, denumerator-vector )` to define it.